# Can not log in - Cookie problem

Tags: php, cookies, forum, mybb

Hello I am trying to set up a MyBB Forum. I tried to get help at MyBB Support and well, there not much help. I am hoping I can fix my problem here.

Well I have just setted up my forums with the following cookie information:

```
var cookieDomain = ".184.173.246.237/~zax/";
    var cookiePath = "/forum/";
    var cookiePrefix = "";
```

As the forum, you can see here. http://184.173.246.237/~zax/forum

When I log into Admin Control Panel I'm logged in, but when clicking to another page it logs me out. When I try to log into the regular account, it says I'm looking in, but I'm not.

Can anybody help me?

I have also read this http://community.mybb.com/thread-74904.html and that did not help ether.

Any help please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried setting cookieDomain to "184.173.246.237" and cookiePath "/~zax/forum/"?